# Loading of 3d model .obj file in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I am new to windows phone 7 programming but I have good experience on the .net windows platform with C#.

So my problem is loading and displaying of 3d model which is .obj file having vertices, faces, normals and texture cords.

How exactly can I do that and what view should I use? If anyone has some sample code then it would be of great help.

thanks

Comment: What 'view'? You are using XNA, aren't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XNA to load files. However, if you're new to XNA, I suggest loading `FBX` files at first to understand how to load in models. `FBX` is natively supported, but `OBJ` requires a custom content pipeline.

There are examples on the AppHub site:

[How to load 3D graphics](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/graphics_3d)

[3D Graphics in XNA](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/?contenttype=0&devarea=6&platform=54&sort=1)

[How to load OBJ files](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/sample/custom_model_importer)

Comment: @Pankaj Rawat - No problem :)